# why is my code not showing image as a link in html

Tags: html, visual-studio

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp"><img src="DFDD.png"></a>
    
</body>
</html>
```

the image is not showing while using links is there something wrong with it, the image is in the same folder...i am using brave browser...the webpage is when run completely blank....really can't figure out whats wrong with it

//this problem occurs only while using the live server extension of vs-code..

Comment: Can you perhaps share the output of `ls` in that directory or a screenshot of the directory if you're not comfortable with the command line?

Comment: the output is completely blank it doesnot shows anything at all

Comment: Try putting the full path to where your picture is located: `C:\the\full\path\DFDD.png`

Comment: @TrooperZ..the problem only occurs while using live server extension of vs-code else it runs perfectly

Comment: if `ls` is blank then there's no files in your directory, and therefore also not your image.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `./YOUR_IMAGE_NAME` instead of just `YOUR_IMAGE_NAME`. I hope it will work.